# Unity resolution fails on Windows server 2008. Why?

Tags: .net, unity-container, windows-server-2008

I have built a console application which uses Unity internally to resolve certain dependencies.

The standalone .exe (after building projects) runs successfully on any machine having windows 8 and VS 2012 installed.

But the problem is, when the same .exe is run on Windows server 2008 (AWS cloud), the application crashes saying "unable to resolve type from unity resolver." with same .config I used on local machine to run it successfully

Why does that happen?

Comment: Can you provide the full exception message?

Comment: also, add more code - registrations and resolve

Comment: @Yacoub Massad : Inner Exception -:System.InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias UnknownRepository could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.TypeResolverImpl.ResolveType(String typeNameOrAlias, Boolean throwIfResolveFails)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.GetMappedType()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.<>c

Comment: __DisplayClass1.<ConfigureContainer>b__0(ContainerConfiguringElement element)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[TItem](IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(IUnityContainer container, String configuredContainerName)

Comment: at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(IUnityContainer container)
   at Product.UnityDI.UnityDependancyResolver..ctor() in e:\parent_path\UnityDependancyResolver.cs:line 21
   at Product.DI.DependancyResolverFactory.GetDependancyResolver() in e:\parent_path\DependancyResolverFactory.cs:line 15
   at Product.DI.DependancyManager..cctor() in e:\parent_path\DependancyManager.cs:line 11

Comment: The problem seems to be around UnknownRepository. Can you include (to the question) parts of your config file that are related to it?